# Remove All Trailing Newlines Before Appending To File

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script, that will append a couple lines to a user generated file. I'm doing the appendage using this methodolgy:

```
write_imports() {
    cat << EOF
# Install for ${package_name}
import ${package_name}

EOF
}

main(){
    imports=$(write_imports)
    echo "$imports" | tee -a $file

}
```

I'm trying to fix an asthetic issue, where sometimes a User's file will have a load of newlines at the end of the file. This means when I run my script we end with a result like so:

```
15: "some user code"
16: 
17:
18:
19:
20:# Install for my_package
21:import my_package
```

When what I want to have is a little cleaner of a result:

```
15: "some user code"
16:# Install for my_package
17:import my_package
```

I want to make sure I don't remove any newlines/whitespace from WITHIN the User's code. I just want to trim off the last trailing lines.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To cleanup empty lines at the end of your file:

with `awk`:

```
awk '/^$/ {n=n "\n";next;} {printf "%s",n; n=""; print;}' your_file
```

or with `sed`:

```
sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba' < your_file
#or
cat your_file | sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba'
```